# Unity MacOS builds not working on Mac systems

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I'm using Unity on Mac.
When I build for Mac, the app works fine on my system. Then, I zip my app (on Mac) and upload it to itch.io. I download the zip from itch.io on my laptop and run it, but an error shows:
“PiranhaMac 19.38.39” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin."

I do not want to ask the people who download my app to open their terminal and type some commands, which seems to be the way this may be fixed.

Comment: what are you trying to acheive by this?

Comment: Upload it on itch.io